# How to Add title to each item of Gallery View items (Images) using android

Tags: android

I have a Gallery Images, and I want to add a title above each item (image).

and also how to put cross button on gallery view items(image)

Comment: show some exapmle of that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorial [Add title to each Image of Gallery Item](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/10/add-title-to-each-item-of-gallery-image/) which might help you.